# Assign a default selected value to dynamically generated select elements in vuejs

Tags: javascript, select, vue.js

I have dynamically generated **multiple select elements** in a page. And I have used

```
v-model = "selected_option"
```

for getting the value of the option selected . But all the select elements in the page have different option values and none of the select elements have any common default option value. All the select elements need to have the first option element as the default selected value. But if I write

```
selected_option = ''
```

then all the select elements are showing blank by default. 
I can get the first option value as the default selected value if I remove

```
v-model = "selected_option"
```

and

```
selected_option = ''
```

but then I am not being able to get the selected value in the **@change** method . Here is my code

```
<div v-if="row.answer_input_type === 'Dropdown'">
  <template v-for="answer in answers">
    <template v-if="answer.AnswerTypeID === row.answer_type_id">
      <select class="dropdown_cl" v-bind:disabled="row.is_enabled == 1 ? false : true" @change="selectChange(row.question_id)"  v-model="selected_option">
        <option v-for="option in answer.AnswerDescription" v-bind:value="option.AnswerMasterID"   >{{option.AnswerDescription}}</option>
      </select>
      <p v-for="option in answer.AnswerDescription">{{option.AnswerMasterID}}</p>
    </template>
  </template>
</div>
```

the default value has been assigned as follows -

```
el : '...'
data : {
         ...
         selected_option: '';
       },
methods: {
          selectChange: function(question_id) {
                           var self=this;
                           alert(question_id + " " + self.selected_option);
                        },
          ...
         },
....
```

I need each select to have the first option as the default selected value. How can I do this? thanks

Comment: You're setting *all* the selects to the same `v-model`?

Comment: yes and that is not working . If I can get the value of option.AnswerMasterID in my method then my problem will be solved

Comment: For sure heh. Why not add a property to `answer`, called `selectedOption` or whatever, and use that for `v-model`? You can also set `answer.selectedOption` to whatever default you want and it will show automagically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick example of what I was explaining in comments.

```
<select v-for="answer in answers"
        v-model="answer.selectedOption">
  <option v-for="option in answer.options" 
          :value="option">
    {{option}}
  </option>
</select>
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/QvjzGa?editors=1010).

If you take this approach, you can manage the default option for each individual select. You also will know what was selected for each answer automatically.

Comment: This is working but I need to have a "select" as the first option. How can I do that?

Comment: @sagarmajumdar Do you mean an option that says "select"?

Comment: @sagarmajumdar Like this. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/dWMBYz?editors=1010